# How to show date in specific format?

Tags: c#

If I use `Date.ToString("D")` in C# then I get `Sunday, October 17, 2010`.

How can I get date `17 october 2010 sunday`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx): `Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy dddd");`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

You will use:
`yourDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy dddd")`

Answer (score 0):

Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy dddd")

Answer (score 0):

```
string yourText = yourDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy dddd").ToLower();
```

I'm assuming that the `ToLower` call is necessary because your example shows *"october"* and *"sunday"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMMM yyyy dddd")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
someDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy dddd")
```

alternatively u can use String.Format with similar parameters